# DayOfYear as per Indian fiscal year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to get a sequence number according to the Indian fiscal year. I tried to write a function using SQL built-in function:

`DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,'2015-04-01')`

but I am facing a challenge to get day number throughout the financial year.

For the financial year 2015: First Day is '2015-04-01' and Last Day is '2016-03-31'.

Note: For this period my financial year 2015 is a leap year, should have 366 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to call from `SELECT` statement. Below is function definition. Parameter @FYear stands for financial year.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FiscalDayNum](@currentDate Date,@FYear Int)
Returns smallint
AS
Begin

DECLARE @Q4days Int
IF (@FYear % 400 ) = 0 OR ((@FYear % 4 ) = 0 AND (@FYear % 100 != 0))
SET @Q4days = 91
ELSE
SET @Q4days = 90

IF (MONTH(@currentDate) Between 4 AND 12)

RETURN ((SELECT DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,@currentDate)- @Q4days))

ELSE IF(MONTH(@currentDate) Between 1 AND 3)

RETURN ((SELECT DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,@currentDate) +
        (SELECT DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,(CONVERT(DATETIME,(CAST(@FYear as VARCHAR(10))+'-12-31'))))
         -@Q4days)))
RETURN 0     
     
END
```

> ```
> SELECT dbo.FiscalDayNum('2015-04-01',YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, '2015-04-01')))
> -- Return 1
>
> SELECT dbo.FiscalDayNum('2016-03-31',YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, '2016-03-31')))
> -- Return 366
> ```

Here `YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, '2015-04-01'))` always returns the financial year of current date.

#### Inline Function version

This is a fairly direct translation of the above scalar function into a more efficient inline table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FiscalDayNum
    (@currentDate date)
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN
    SELECT FiscalDayNum =
        CASE
            WHEN MONTH(@currentDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 12
            THEN DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @currentDate)- V.Q4days
            ELSE 
                DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @currentDate) + 
                DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,
                    CONVERT(
                        datetime, 
                        CONVERT(varchar(4), F.FYear) + '-12-31',
                        120)) - V.Q4days
        END
    FROM (VALUES(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @currentDate)))) AS F (FYear)
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN (F.FYear % 400) = 0 
                    OR ((F.FYear % 4) = 0 AND (F.FYear % 100 != 0))
                THEN 91
                ELSE 90
            END
    ) AS V (Q4days);
```

Usage:

```
SELECT FDN.FiscalDayNum
FROM dbo.FiscalDayNum('20150401') AS FDN;

SELECT FDN.FiscalDayNum
FROM dbo.FiscalDayNum('20160331') AS FDN;
```

Returns the same results as the original function.

Comment: A scalar function is not a good idea if this is going to be called for every row in a query.

Answer (score 10):

The sequence number of a day in a year that begins on april 1 can be calculated this way:

```
SELECT 1+
       DATEDIFF(day,
           DATEFROMPARTS(
               DATEPART(year, DATEADD(month, -3, [Date])),
               4,
               1),
           [Date]) AS FYdayNumber
FROM tableWithDates;
```

In essence, we're subtracting three months from the current date, then using that *year* to create a start-of-year date (*year*, april, 1), then calculating the number of days between that start-of-year date and the current date. Finally, add 1 in order to make the sequence start at 1.

If you just want the first day of your fiscal year, you can use

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(
           DATEPART(year, DATEADD(month, -3, [Date])),
           4,
           1) AS firstDayOfFY
FROM tableWithDates;
```

As @MarkSinkinson pointed out in another answer, avoid (user-defined) scalar functions for performance and parallelisation reasons.